# what is the difference between webdriverwait polling and fluentwait polling when both can poll for element every mentioned seconds(selenium webdriver)

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,180).pollingEvery(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'sweet-alert')]/p")));


new FluentWait(driver).withTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Please have a look at the above two waits.
both are going to wait for maximum 180 seconds and both are going to check for element every 10 seconds then how do they differ?

Thanks,
Pradeep

Comment: Does this question help you?
http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12866/how-fluentwait-is-different-from-webdriverwait

Comment: @PaulMuir - this question is probably a duplicate of the one you linked. Voting to delete as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you view the [source for WebDriverWait](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.java) you can see that it extends the [FluentWait](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/1e39027d0c846baf3dbd977d162821782a621417/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.java)`<WebDriver>` class.

Ultimately, if you're using the `FluentWait<WebDriver>` it is the same just uses some defaults in the constructors from what I can tell. I'd use WebDriverWait over FluentWait for multiple reasons but primarily due to it being the most familiar implementation. If there is extensions built that you wish to use they are more likely to use the WebDriverWait than the FluentWait, which will likely cause you problems.

Now if you wanted to use, for example, `FluentWait<WebElement>`, this might be beneficial.